# Where to look for information on Architecture of High Scalable Website like Orbitz, Amazon, Ebay, Linkedin etc?

Tags: architecture

I am willing to learn about different architectures of highly scalable web applications like gmail, google, youtube, amazon, orbitz, linkedin, ebay etc. and would certainly appreciate if someone can point me to some online resource/book from where I can learn about details of their architecture and trade offs in selecting a particular design over other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[InfoQ](http://www.infoq.com/) often has some good presentations on highly scalable architectures:

[Orbitz](http://www.infoq.com/interviews/Architecture-Brian-Zimmer)

[Amazon](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/vogels-amazon-platform)

[Ebay](http://www.infoq.com/articles/ebay-scalability-best-practices)

Answer (score 4):

Add [High Scalability](http://highscalability.com) to your list.

Answer (score 1):

Too late to come up with a real list, but...

Some interesting posts from facebook can be found [here](http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=23844338919)

Answer (score 0):

See also several of the following titles:

- [Building Scalable Web Sites: Building, scaling, and optimizing the next generation of web applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596102356)
- [High Performance Web Sites: Essential Knowledge for Front-End Engineers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529309)
- [High Performance MySQL: Optimization, Backups, Replication, and More](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596101716)
- [Scalable Internet Architectures](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/067232699X)